# Python error: unexpected expression syntax: copying files to a folder script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program to copy files to a destination folder.
I am encountering a problem with unexpected expression syntax.

Below is the script

```py
import os
import shutil

p = Path(os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r"/PycharmProjects/found_files")
p.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
input_path = input(r"Enter path of the directory: ")
original_path = input_path
target_path = (os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'/PycharmProjects/found_files)'
shutil.copy(original_path,os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'/PycharmProjects/found_files')
```

I am encountering that error on the last line of code.

*Error: unexpected expression syntax* on the last line.

Comment: @Matiiss mind If I get your help? Thanks

Comment: please add the error message to your question

Comment: @toydarian may you please check. I added the error message

Comment: never mind, you have a misplaced quote: `(os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'/PycharmProjects/found_files)'` it should be `.../found_files')` in the line before the last one

Comment: *Unexpected expression syntax:10* it

Comment: @toydarian this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PacY/PycharmProjects/p2/f2.py", line 10, in <module>
    shutil.copy(original_path,os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'/PycharmProjects/found_files')
  File "C:\Users\PacY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 415, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\PacY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/PaCY'

Answer (score 0):

Caused by a typo, you have

```py
target_path = (os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'/PycharmProjects/found_files)'
```

it should be

```py
target_path = (os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'/PycharmProjects/found_files')
```

Comment: I'm getting a traceback

Comment: After entering a path, I am getting this error:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PacY/PycharmProjects/p2/f2.py", line 10, in <module>
    shutil.copy(input_path,os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'/PycharmProjects/found_files')
  File "C:\Users\PacY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 415, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\PacY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:/Users/PaCY/Documents'

Comment: That is a different question. `[Errno 13] Permission denied` means, that the user running the script does not have permission to access the file.

Comment: how I get access to file, btw I'm running as administrator

Comment: maybe that is your problem, try running it as user `PaCY`

Comment: User *PaCY* shows * [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: It is hard to debug that without access to the machine it is happening on.